# passport authentication callback not calling passport middleware

Tags: json, node.js, passport.js, json-web-token

I am trying to test if a GET request to a specific route is protected by using JSON Web Tokens with passport JwtStrategy; however, it seems like the `passport.use` middleware function I have in my `server.js` file is not executing. The console.log I have in there never shows up in my shell/terminal. My login route works, but not the profile route. I am using postman and I entered `http://localhost:3000/profile` for the GET method and in the `Headers` tab I chose Authorization for Key and for the Value I copied and pasted the long JSON web token string, but it keeps saying unauthorized. That is because my passport.use function is never getting executed.

//Server.js file

```
var JwtStrategy = require("passport-jwt").Strategy;
var ExtractJwt = require("passport-jwt").ExtractJwt;

var User = require("../models/user");
var config = require('./secret');

app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

let options = {};
//pass token back and forth
options.jwtFromRequest = ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeader();
options.secretOrKey = config;
passport.use(new JwtStrategy(options, (jwt_payload, done) => {
  *******************************************
  //this console log doesn't show up in shell which makes be believe its never getting here
  *******************************************
  console.log("JWT PAYLOAD", jwt_payload)
  User.getUserById(jwt_payload._id, (err, user) => {
    if(err){
      return done(err, false);
    }

    if(user){ //null for error
      return done(null, user);
    }else{
      return done(null, false);
    }
  });
}));
```

//Routes file where the passport.authenticate callback is called

```
var passport = require('passport');
var jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
var secret = require('../config/secret')

var User = require('../models/user');

router.post('/login', (req, res) => {
    var username = req.body.username;
    var password = req.body.password;
    console.log("SECRET2", secret);
    console.log("SECRET", secret.secret);
    User.getUserByUsername(username, (err, user) => {
        if(err){
            throw err;
        }
        if(!user){
            return res.json({ success: false, msg: "User not found"});
        }

        User.comparePassword(password, user.password, (err, isMatch) => {
            if(err){
                throw err;
            }
            if(isMatch){
                var token = jwt.sign(user, secret.secret, {
                    expiresIn: 604800 //1 week in seconds, token expires and requires to log back in
                });

                console.log('TOKEN IN LOGIN ROUTE', token)

                res.json({
                    //tokens are then stored in local storage or cookie
                    success: true,
                    token: 'JWT ' + token,
                    user: {
                        id: user._id,
                        name: user.name,
                        username: user.username,
                        email: user.email
                    }
                });
            }else{
                return res.json({ success: false, msg: "Incorrect password"});
            }
        });
    });
});

router.get('/profile', passport.authenticate('jwt', {session:false}), (req, res) => {
    res.json({user: req.user});
});
```

//User model

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');

var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var UserSchema = new Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    trim: true,
    required: "First Name is Required"
  },
  email: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  username: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  password: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  }
});

var User = mongoose.model("User", UserSchema);

module.exports = User;

//Alternate syntax for exporting Schema
// var User = module.exports = mongoose.model("User", UserSchema);

module.exports.getUserById = function(id, callback){
    User.findById(id, callback);
}

module.exports.getUserByUsername = function(username, callback){
    var query = { username: username }
    User.findOne(query, callback);
}

//Custom User model function that will take in the newUser object and hash the password.
module.exports.addUser = function(newUser, callback){
    bcrypt.genSalt(10, (err, salt) => {
        bcrypt.hash(newUser.password, salt, (err, hash) => {
            if(err){
                throw err
            }

            newUser.password = hash;
            newUser.save(callback);
        });
    });
}

module.exports.comparePassword = function(password, hash, callback){
    bcrypt.compare(password, hash, (err, isMatch) => {
        if(err){
            throw err
        }
        callback(null, isMatch);
    });
}
```

Update: 
I tried putting a space after 'JWT' in for the value for Authorization in the postman, but it still does not work and the console log is not showing. Is it because I am somehow not exporting or linking the `passport.use` I have defined in my `server.js` to my GET '/profile' route in my routes file?

Update 2: Added model and Login route

Comment: The value of the `Authorization` header has to look like this: `JWT the-actual-token`. Look [here](https://github.com/themikenicholson/passport-jwt#include-the-jwt-in-requests).

Comment: Do you mean when I am testing on postman the GET route to profile? I have type set to Authorization and the value as the entire jwt token I pasted. Unless i need that JWT space then the token. But im not sure this is issue as the Authenticate (passport.use) method never seems to get called because the console log never shows.

Comment: Yes, you need to prefix the token in the value with "JWT-space". Like it says in the documentation I linked to: https://github.com/themikenicholson/passport-jwt#include-the-jwt-in-requests My guess is that the strategy is never called because the `Authorization` header is "invalid".

Comment: Okay, I tried adding the space but it is still saying unauthorized and the console log is still not showing. Do i need the JWT plus the "-" then a space followed by the token?

Comment: No. Say your token is "ABCDEF", then the header value should look like this: `JWT ABCDEF`

Comment: Yes, I tried both ways, but the results are same. It seems like my passport.use is never being executed either way since the console log I have in my original post is never showing in my terminal.

Comment: And are you sure that the token that you are passing is valid? Only when it can find a valid token will the callback get called. Here's a standalone version that works for me: https://gist.github.com/robertklep/8183ef63e9520ce653934092cb8001f3

Comment: Yes, I am copying the token that gets returned from the POST login route displayed in Postman.

Comment: Can you add the code from the login route to your question as well?

Comment: okay, just added

Comment: You are generating the token with `secret.secret`, but in the strategy options, you're using `secret`, which doesn't seem right. As an aside: `expiresIn` should be in milliseconds, not seconds (it's now set to expire in 10 minutes), and strictly speaking, `JWT ` should not be part of the token.

Comment: I have JWT there so I can have it returned to me in Postman for testing the Profile route. Also, I don't think the expiresIn has any relevancy. And the secret issue shouldnt be a problem either but Ill try

Comment: I tried changing secret.secret to just secret but I get an error saying secret must be string or buffer so I am sure that is not the issue. Also, even if the JWT token format is incorrect, should't the passport.use middle still be called and showing the console and returning an error? The problem is the passport.use never get called for some reason.

Comment: @robertklep Yes you were correct. It was an issue with the secret. Thank you

Comment: I realized last night that your token contains the full "user" document, _including_ password field. I don't think you want to expose that much through a token (tokens are not encrypted, anyone can read them).

Comment: Yes. Thanks for the tip. I made sure the password is not sent back. However do you know if sending back MongoDB user _id and setting it in a html "data" attribute or equivalent is safe? The reason to do this would be to reference users when for example going to a users profile page.

Comment: It's quite common to use those id's clientside (in URL's or otherwise) to identify users, so that's not a big deal.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is necessary to include more code to see your issue, but it seems like the strategy is not being exported correctly. When you create a new strategy, you can include an 'alias' to use it in the entry point:

```
passport.use('local-login', new JwtStrategy(options, (jwt_payload, done) => {
    ....
}

router.get('/profile', passport.authenticate('local-login', {session:false}), (req, res) => {
    res.json({user: req.user});
});
```